# Can we extract text contents from evernote file

Tags: java, evernote

I am working on a project which needs to extract text contents from Evernote file. Is there any Java libraries that helps doing this? Evernote API doesn't seem to support this.

Please let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Java SDK](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-java) and the API reference is [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/).

For example, if you want to get the content of a note, you can use [`NoteStore.getNote`](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) with `withContent` true to get `Note` object.  Or, if you are talking about attachment file, using it with `withResourcesData` true might help. You can also get the file using [`NoteStore.getResoruce`](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResource) if you already know `guid`. For more details about resources on Evernote, see [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Resources.php).

You can start using/learning Evernote API from [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a Java SDK:

`https://github.com/evernote`

I got that straight from the Evernote Cloud API page.